# Getting "Unable to load plugin herokgit" when trying to use heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku

Has anyone ever gotten this error or know what it relates to? I got absolutely *nothing* doing a google search. Not able to use heroku right now as a result - basically any heroku command I enter at prompt gives me this error

```
ERROR: Unable to load plugin herogit: undefined method `get_credentials' for class `Heroku::Command::Auth'
```

I'm using ruby 1.9.2 and the heroku-gem 2.3.6 on Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty). This is probably the first time I've had to use heroku since having upgraded. I was surely using it without issue on 10.10, but I might have just forgotten to set something up. That I'm not finding anything online about this error is weird though.

Comment: I just tried running from 1.8.7 (using rvm) to no avail. Still same issue. I'm gonna submit a ticket to the Heroku support guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with the folks at Heroku, they suggested uninstalling the herogit plugin to see if things worked. Doing so resulted in the error above going away, but I realized that I still couldn't turn the maintenance mode off and was getting a permission denied message. I'm pretty sure that the permission denied message was the same as I was getting when the error was still showing itself.

Eventually I realized that I was using the remote name instead of the actual app name when passing to the --app flag (I have a stage and a production deployment). Because the error message mentioned credentials, I failed to realize that the issue that was *actually* preventing me from using the heroku CLI was unrelated to the herogit plugin. I'm still not sure why the herogit plugin stopped working after switching systems, but don't really care that much at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem will be with the plugin and not with Heroku

Comment: Yeah, that's my suspicion as well - that is, that something will be amiss with the gem and not the hosting service.

Comment: My aopologies - I misunderstood, and thought that you were saying that the problem was with the heroku gem and not with the Heroku cloud. Silly looking back on it, because you did say "plugin", as did the error. Anyway, thanks for your response.